# Resetting stopwatch PyQT5 program

Tags: python

I have created a Stopwatch program in PyQT5, i am having some issues with resetting the timer. I want to be able to reset the timer even while the timer is running. Currently, i can only reset the timer while the timer is stopped. Where it will only reset the timers text until you press start where it will carry on from previous time.

```
class MyGUI(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        super(MyGUI, self).__init__()
        uic.loadUi("stopwatch.ui", self)
        self.show()

        self.running = False 
        self.started = False 

        self.passed = 0
        self.previous_passed = 0

        self.start_s1.clicked.connect(self.start_timer)
        self.stop_s1.clicked.connect(self.stop_timer)
        self.reset_s1.clicked.connect(self.reset_timer)

            
    def start_timer(self):
        if not self.running:
            self.running = True
            threading.Thread(target=self.stopwatch).start()
        

    def stop_timer(self):
        if self.running:
            self.running = False

    
    def reset_timer(self):
        hours = 0
        mins = 0
        secs = 0
        self.timer_s1.setText("00:00:00")
        

    def format_time_string(self, time_passed):
        secs = time_passed % 60
        mins = time_passed // 60
        hours = mins // 60
        return f"{int(hours):02d}:{int(mins):02d}:{int(secs):02d}"


    def stopwatch(self):
        start = time.time()
        if self.started:
            until_now = self.passed
        else:
            until_now = 0
            self.started = True

        while self.running:
            self.passed = time.time() - start + until_now
            self.timer_s1.setText(self.format_time_string(self.passed))



def main():
    app = QApplication([])
    window = MyGUI()
    app.exec_()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

I have tried resetting the hours,mins,secs etc in different spots. Not seeming too want to reset lol.